# Single line delimited text

Tags: regex

I have a single line text containing an invoice's rows, extracted from a pdf.

I should parse it, getting rows as output tokens.

Here's a snippet:

> 1 NR 0PR 18OV DHO1O154 OCCHIALE ACETATO DONNA VISTA 1 NR 0PR 18OV
>   NAG1O152 OCCHIALE ACETATO DONNA VISTA 1 NR 0PR 61QV 7AX1O156 OCCHIALE
>   METALLO UOMO VISTA Descrizione Causale Vendita 2 NR 0AN4007 41 / 87 66
>   OCCHIALE NYLON UOMO SOLE Descrizione Causale Vendita 1 NR 0EA4001
>   50638G56 Valeria OCCHIALE NYLON UOMO SOLE Descrizione Causale Vendita
>   - Pag 1 di 3 - Segue - 1 NR 0PO3042S 972 / M351 Sofia OCCHIALE ACETATO UOMO SOLE Descrizione Causale Vendita 1 NR 0AN3048 502 / 8G30 Valeria
>   OCCHIALE METALLO UOMO SOLE Descrizione Causale Vendita 6 NR 0DG4204
>   27648764 OCCHIALE ACETATO UOMO SOLE Descrizione Causale Vendita 1 NR
>   0OX3123 31230453 Valeria OCCHIALE ACCIAIO UOMO VISTA

I want to get, as a token, for example the first:

*1 NR 0PR 18OV DHO1O154 OCCHIALE ACETATO DONNA VISTA*

Explained, my token should be:

- starting with *integer*+*space*+NR+*space*
- containing whatever I can find after the start, strings, numbers, whatever...
- ending before: the next "X+NR" starting token, fixed strings (such as "Descrizione Causale Vendita") or the end of file.

Using this regex `(\b\d+\b NR)` I can match all the X+NR starting tokens, how can I select the next part, before the next X+NR token?

Notice the title! I have all in one single line, so... *no new lines separators*!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the regex you have so far, you can use a positive lookahead:

```
(?:\b\d+\b NR).*?(?=\b\d+\b NR|$)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/yY7jF3)

Each colour indicates a different match.

`(?= ... )` is a positive lookahead which doesn't count as a match. Therefore, you get matches up until and before the next `\b\d\b NR` or end of string `$`.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat simplified version of @Jerry's answer:

```
\d NR(?:(?!\d NR).)*
```